# How can I permanently disable IntelliSense includes not found message in Visual Studio Code for C++ projects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Ho to get rid of the IntelliSense includes not found message?
I can click on 'Don't show again' as often as I like.
The message pops up again, as soon as I open the folder next time.
Includes can not be found, they are not existing at that stage.
(Precompiler with macros that need to be resolved, etc.)

[image]

Comment: Drop the stock C++ extension if favor of Clangd? (which I find to be better in other ways too)